# m3u8 not playing in android 4.0.3

Tags: android, api, android-emulator, stream, http-live-streaming

I have played http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8 in Android 4.0.3 (API 15) in the emulators browser, it plays only with audio but without video. however when I downloaded all the files along with the m3u8, the browser is unable to play... Why does this happen? Any idea?... I'm stuck in this since 20 days. I even tried encoding the files myself, they all play very well in Safari on a Mac, but not in the emulator or the real device.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you want to play this video in any browser. I use default video player and `m3u8 video` plays without any problem. API Level must be higher than 14 (Android 4.0+).

If you want to start the video from your own Activity using URL, try the code below. It's tested and works on real android device.

```
String url = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: As you said, code is working fine. I am able to see the Video view but not able to watch the video.

Comment: Also Can you please give me the code to play the .m3u8 extension videos in the Android's VideoView. Please give me the code. :)

Comment: I don't know how would it work in Android's VideoView and I haven't try it. In the code above video is started in the default video player your Android phone uses.

Comment: Use ""application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" as type to launch a list of all multimedia apps;-)